# Как заменить все значения NULL в таблице mysql, при этом не добавляя другие повторы?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE catalogs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Название раздела',
    UNIQUE unique_name(name(10))
) COMMENT = 'Разделы интернет-магазина';

INSERT IGNORE INTO catalogs VALUES 
    (NULL, 'Процессоры'),
    (NULL, 'Оперативная память'),
    (NULL, 'Процессоры'),
    (NULL, 'Материнские платы'),
    (NULL, NULL),
    (NULL, NULL);

UPDATE IGNORE
    catalogs 
SET
    name = 'empty'
WHERE
    name IS NULL;
```

---

В этом случае в таблице меняется только первое значение NULL, а задача изменить все значение. Самое простое убрать UNIQUE, тогда все значения NULL сменяться на empty. Но хочется, чтобы при этом дублирующие значения также не добавлялись в таблицу. Без двух строк с процессорами, как бы.

Comment: Озвученные желания противоречат друг другу - так что где-то придётся подвинуться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE catalogs 
SET name = CONCAT('empty #', id)
WHERE name IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2edc0c80ffe210d5785056b039a23b1f)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все понял